# Tone generator generates a second tone

Tags: java, android, javasound, android-audiomanager, audiotrack

I am trying to make a simple signalgenerator for isochronic pulsating sounds.

Basically a "beatFrequency" is controlling the amplitude variation of the main (pitch) frequency.

It works pretty well except that for some pitch frequencies above 4-5 K Hz, there is a second tone generated with lower frequency.
It's not for all frequencies but for quite many I can definetly hear a second tone.

What can this be? Some kind of resonance? I tried increasing the sampling rate, but its not changing anything, and using 44100 should be enough up to around 20 KHz, if I understand correctly?

I really can't figure it out on my own, so thankful for all help!

Here is an example code with beatFreequency 1 Hz, Pitch frequency 5000 Hz and samplerate 44100.

```
public void playSound() {

double beatFreq = 1;
double pitch = 5000;
int mSampleRate = 44100;

    AudioTrack mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,   mSampleRate,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
        256, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

int loopLength = 2 * this.mSampleRate;

while (isPlaying) {
    double[] mSound = new double[loopLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < loopLength; i = i + 1) {
       mSound[i] = beatFreq*Math.sin((1.0*Math.PI * i/(this.mSampleRate/pitch)));
       mBuffer[i] = (short) (mSound[i] * Short.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    mAudioTrack.play();
    mAudioTrack.write(mBuffer, 0, loopLength);

}
}
```

Here is (added) an image of the frequencies when I play the tone 4734Hz.. And for example there is a rather large peak at around 1100 Hz as well as many higher.

[image]

The code is now just using the pitch, I have removed the beat Freq:

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are using `beatFreq*Math.sin((1.0*Math.PI * i/(this.mSampleRate/pitch)));`to determine the frequency (Missing some sort of assignment here)

However, mSampleRate and pitch are int values, leading to an integer division instead of a double division. For special cases for pitch and samplerate , this will result into lower frequencies than intended. For greater pitch values the effect should getting worse.

Try to use double instead of int, that should get rid of the problem.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to put in one line mSound[i]. I have made the pitch and beatFreq double values now, but the problem is still there, I can def hear lower tones being generated in parallel to the intended.

Comment: Can you find out if the higher tone you are hearing is a multiple of the lower second one? Or best some examples of the frequencies where it is happening and not happening? Maybe that will give more insight into the problem. I would try it with a mono channel

Comment: I don't know what the extra tone is, I wills if I can measure it somehow ... I can't really find any pattern in where I can hear it and notbut I now also realise that even when I don't hear a second tone, the tone generated is not the right one,

Comment: Going up the scale in frequency the tone sometimes go lower instead of higher for some tones above 4000 Hz. For example 4369 sounds higher than 5242. And 6335 Hz sounds higher than 7305. For others its not that way, 5242 sounds lower than 5971, and 6699 sounds lower than 7427.

Comment: I have edited the question above now to include an image spectrum of the extra frequencies being generated.

Comment: So now its just a pure sine wave being computed, still many other tones (multiples and parts of the main tone) are being generated, as I am not doing any other modification of the signal, it seems this is something inherit in the AudioTrack generation of the sound? Could there be something to be done with the signal after it has been generated? Or rather make something different in the calculation of the signal?

Comment: I doubt that the answer to your problem is something within the tone generation. I thought about how android processed tones but still that would not explain two different tones like that.

Two things that I came up with:
1. "AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT": Can you try to set this to a non compressed format to try? Maybe the algorithm behind it is compressing in some sort that results in a second tone.

2. Are you able to test the same code on a different, non android system (Or on another android device)? That would exclude android or the android sound engine as the problem

Comment: I tried setting the format to: AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT, but then there is no sound at all coming out, not sure if I need to change something else using PCM_FLOAT? I have tested it on several different virtual devices but on the same computer, I have not tried it on a real android device yet as I couldn't get that to work with my current galaxy s7 for some reason.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat

I think the problem is that ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT only accepts values between -1 and 1. Therefore you are exceeding the maximum /minimum values.

But other than that it does not seem to be the solution..

Comment: What would be a non compressed format then? How do I set it?

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting answer, after better understanding question, that the OP wants to do amplitude modulation.

Yes, Java can do Amplitude Modulation. I've made a passable cricket sound, for example, by taking a 4.9KHz tone and modulating the volume at 66Hz, and giving the resulting tone an AR envelope.

In your code, the variable beatFreq remains constant over an entire for-loop. Isn't your intention to vary this as well over the course of time?

I think you should simultaneously compute the beatFreq wave value in its own function (but also using the varying i), and multiply that result (scaled to range from 0 to 1) against the value computed for the faster tone.

---

** EDIT

---

To move redundant calculations out of the inner loop the following is a possibility:

Have the following as instance variables:

```
private double incr;
private double incrSum;
private final double TWO_PI = Math.PI * 2;
```

Have the following calculation done only one time, in your constructor:

```
    incr = pitch / audioFmt.getSampleRate();
    incr *= TWO_PI;
```

This assumes `pitch` is a value stated in Hertz, and `audioFormat' is the Java AudioFormat being used. With Android, I don't know how the audio format sample rate is stored or accessed.

With this in place you can have a method that returns the next double PCM value with some very simple code:

```
private double getNextSinePCM()
{
    incrSum += incr;
    if (incrSum > TWO_PI)
    {
        incrSum -= TWO_PI;
    }
    return Math.sin(incrSum);
}
```

Note: do not reset `incrSum` to zero as you stated in your comment. This can introduce a discontinuity.

If you have a second tone, it would get its own increment and running sum. This the two results, you can then multiply them to get amplitude modulation.

Now, as to the question as how to properly convert the PCM double value returned to something Android can use, I can't give you a definitive answer as I am not running Android.

Just a comment: it seems to me you are enthusiastic about working with sound, but maybe self-taught or lagging a bit in basic programming techniques. Moving redundant calculations outside of a loop is kind of fundamental. So is the ability to make simple test cases for testing assumptions and trouble-shooting. As you go forward, I want to encourage you to dedicate some time to developing these fundamentals as well as pursuing the interest in sound! You might check out the StackOverflow code reading group as a resource for more tips. I am also self-taught and have learned a lot from there as well as the code-reading course at JavaRanch called "CattleDrive".

Comment: Well, isn't it an AM, as I am letting one sine wave (beat frequency) modulate the amplitude of the Pitch (carrier frequency). 

Not sure I understood all you wrote, but I want to generate a pulsating sound with a specifik pitch, and I don't think phase modulation would do this, so do you think there is any way in Java to make a pulsating sound with one beat Freq and one Pitch, or is it a limitation in the Java language then?

Comment: Added new answer based on understanding that your goal is to do amplitude modulation.

Comment: The idea is that the beat frequency is a variable that can be controlled from the app interface, but for now I can keep it a constant as its the pitch tone that behaves weird. As in the image above, there are several tones being generated where it should be only one, both multiples and factors of the main tone ... not sure why this is and how I can get around it.

Comment: I took a look at "ring modulation" on wikipedia. I think you may have set that up for yourself. Article says it arises when the two signals are multiplied together (convolution, in effect). Output of ring modulator includes sum and difference tones. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_modulation If you are getting an audible low tone, your "1 Hz" tone could well be a rather different pitch.

Comment: Yes, I think is what happens ... I have added an image of the frequencies out when I play a 4734 Hz signal, and there is many peaks, for example one at around 1100 Hz that is what I hear ...But I get this effect now even when there are not 2 signals multiplied, I have removed the beatFreq, and now just generate the pitch.

Comment: Need to be able to produce a simple sine before going forward! Check if there is a discontinuity between buffers? The way you are handling the phase (via variable i) looks problematic when going from buffer to buffer. If your frequency is not a multiple of the sample rate, you are probably getting a big jump between the last i and the first i of the next.

Comment: Yeah thats true, before I hade a problem with a clipping sound between the loops, but for some reason, this problem disappeared. Do you have a suggestion how to do this in a different manner to avoid discontinuity between the buffers?

Comment: Move variables that need to provide continuity to be set up outside the buffer filling loop. I'd consider defining an increment (calculated once, from the frequency and the sample rate) that gets progressively added to a running sum variable. (Nice side effect, not doing division every iteration.) Also, test the running sum variable and when it reaches the looping point (2PI), subtract one loop, thus ensuring the argument to your sign function never overflows.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I tried, it but don't think I did it right ... basically, outside the loop I calculated a variable inc.

double inc = pitch/this.mSampleRate; 
double sum = 0;

And then inside the loop I added:

sum = sum + inc;
if(sum > 2.0*Math.PI) sum = 0;

and changed the calculation to:

Math.sin(1.0*Math.PI * sum)

Am I thinking wrong here? The result is a weird sound, at low freq its kind of clipping a lot, like the sampling rate is way to low, the pitch also sounds like a lower frequency, and there is even more multiple overtones etc than before.